# How is net revenue calculated?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

How  is net revenue calculated? Which expenses are in the equation?

In other words, does the net revenue calculate that I will purchase every resources from the market except the electricity, produces the final good and sell it on the market?

[image]

Comment: It would help to list the market prices for the resources.

Comment: To my understanding it's the sell price of the product minus the buy price of the supplies. However, I don't think it considers potential bonuses (i.e. If you turn the option on under gameplay to display net revenue the build icons seen on the left of your screenshot will show their potential revenue, however depending on bonuses this may increase). I've had it say that I would make -$6 from chemicals but since I could place with a +75% adj. bonus and with optimization center upgrades maxed I had somewhere around +$300 net revenue.